# Using uploader.php class to handle multiple file upload using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I want to use the answer in `link` to upload multiple pdf files using uploader.php class.

I am using jquery and php. below is my code, now i want to handle and upload files using uploader class in the link.

Using this code i am getting undefined index txtFile in line no 70 and 71 in uploader.php

The uploader class is

```html
<?php

    class Uploader
    {
        private $destinationPath;
        private $errorMessage;
        private $extensions;
        private $allowAll;
        private $maxSize;
        private $uploadName;
        private $seqnence;
        public $name='Uploader';
        public $useTable    =false;

        function setDir($path){
            $this->destinationPath  =   $path;
            $this->allowAll =   false;
        }

        function allowAllFormats(){
            $this->allowAll =   true;
        }

        function setMaxSize($sizeMB){
            $this->maxSize  =   $sizeMB * (1024*1024);
        }

        function setExtensions($options){
            $this->extensions   =   $options;
        }

        function setSameFileName(){
            $this->sameFileName =   true;
            $this->sameName =   true;
        }
        function getExtension($string){
            $ext    =   "";
            try{
                    $parts  =   explode(".",$string);
                    $ext        =   strtolower($parts[count($parts)-1]);
            }catch(Exception $c){
                    $ext    =   "";
            }
            return $ext;
    }

        function setMessage($message){
            $this->errorMessage =   $message;
        }

        function getMessage(){
            return $this->errorMessage;
        }

        function getUploadName(){
            return $this->uploadName;
        }
        function setSequence($seq){
            $this->imageSeq =   $seq;
    }

    function getRandom(){
        return strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).rand(1111,9999).rand(11,99).rand(111,999);
    }
    function sameName($true){
        $this->sameName =   $true;
    }
        function uploadFile($fileBrowse){
            $result =   false;
            $size   =   $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["size"];
            $name   =   $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["name"];
            $ext    =   $this->getExtension($name);
            if(!is_dir($this->destinationPath)){
                $this->setMessage("Destination folder is not a directory ");
            }else if(!is_writable($this->destinationPath)){
                $this->setMessage("Destination is not writable !");
            }else if(empty($name)){
                $this->setMessage("File not selected ");
            }else if($size>$this->maxSize){
                $this->setMessage("Too large file !");
            }else if($this->allowAll || (!$this->allowAll && in_array($ext,$this->extensions))){

        if($this->sameName==false){
                    $this->uploadName   =  $this->imageSeq."-".substr(md5(rand(1111,9999)),0,8).$this->getRandom().rand(1111,1000).rand(99,9999).".".$ext;
                }else{
            $this->uploadName=  $name;
        }
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileBrowse]["tmp_name"],$this->destinationPath.$this->uploadName)){
                    $result =   true;
                }else{
                    $this->setMessage("Upload failed , try later !");
                }
            }else{
                $this->setMessage("Invalid file format !");
            }
            return $result;
        }

        function deleteUploaded(){
            unlink($this->destinationPath.$this->uploadName);
        }

    }

?>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#add_more").click(function(e){  
         var current_count = $('input[type="file"]').length;
         var next_count = current_count + 1;
         $('#file_upload').append('<div class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type = "file" name = "file_'+next_count+ '"/></div> ');
         
        });  
    });
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
  <link href="includes/Styles/style_boot.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

 </head>
 <body>
 
  <?php echo $header; ?>
  <hr />
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-8">
   <?php
   
   if(Session::exists('home')){
    
   echo  Session::flash('home') ;
   }
   
   ?>   
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container">
    <form id="file_upload" action="upload_file.php"  method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="row">
      <div  class="col-md-3 ">
       <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file_1">
      </div>
     </div><br>
     <div class="row">
       <div  class="col-md-3">
        <a id="add_more" href="#">Add More Files</a>
       </div>
      
      <div class="col-md3">
       <input class="btn-success" type="submit" value="upload" />
      </div>
     </div>

    </form>
   </div>
   </div>
  <hr />
 <?php echo $footer; ?>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/common/ext.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to use this code to handle files in php but what should i use in place of txtFile in this line "if($uploader->uploadFile('txtFile'))";

```html
<?php
$uploader   =   new Uploader();
$uploader->setDir('uploads/images/');
$uploader->setExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'));  //allowed extensions list//
$uploader->setMaxSize(.5);                          //set max file size to be allowed in MB//

if($uploader->uploadFile('txtFile')){   //txtFile is the filebrowse element name //     
    $image  =   $uploader->getUploadName(); //get uploaded file name, renames on upload//

}else{//upload failed
    $uploader->getMessage(); //get upload error message 
}


?>
```

Comment: Sorry, please edit your question above (there is an `edit` button below it) and fix the link you wanted to post right at the beginning of the text. Also I cannot spot that class definition you refer to in the code you posted, so how are we meant to help? And how do you expect us to _guess_ what lines 70 and 71 are in the code you did not post?

Comment: I am sorry about the missing link.

Comment: The uploader.php class was there in the link. I am editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The undefined error is because you want to access a variable which is not initialized. Check this before:

```
if(isset($var))
```

For accessing the POSTed files, use something like this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $info) {
    if(substr($key, 0, 5) != "file_")
        continue;
    // Handle the file - file information at $info as array
}
```

---

Or use the `multiple` tag in your file input - then you even can select more than one file:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

Then it works so in PHP:

```
foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file) {
    // Handle the file - file information at $file as array
}
```

Comment: 1. is it mandatory to use foreach loop in case of print_r($_FILES).

Comment: 2. var_dump($_FILES) gives array(0){}

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` gives an empty array? This is very crazy, because you use the correct enctype at form. When does it gives an empty array? Even if you just submit one file?

Comment: yes  Richard  it gives an empty array in both cases for single and multiple file.

Answer (score 0):

You from method is `get` it should be `POST`, the name of your file upload field is `file_1` but you try to access the file via `txtFile`.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to ask what should i use instead of txtFile.

Comment: I used GET for testing purpose only